# Visual Studio 2017/2019| How can I fix Live up and down using alt+arrow(up/down)

Tags: visual-studio, line, arrows

Visual Studio 2017/2019| How can I fix Live up and down using **alt+arrow(up/down)** 
For **alt+ arrow Down** everything ok.
But if I sent **alt + arrow up** --> go to up to method

Comment: Sorry *LINE will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found answer**

The only way I have found to get rid of this is to

1. Close the solution
2. Delete .vs\solution\v15.suo (hidden)
3. Re-open the solution

It happens in v15.4.2. and happens every time you switch between branches using Git where dependent code changes.

Cleaning and rebuilding does not fix it.

Restarting VS does not fix it.

The errors are all Intellisense and you can filter these out by changing the Error List window from "Build + IntelliSense" to "Build Only" but the underlined in red text remains (even though there are no build errors).

This is happening to multiple developers in our team and is a fairly recent bug as far as we can tell.